# use count as total of one table as int field in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have two tables [Analises_Calendario] and [Locais Recolha] linked by the field "LIDEntid".

So I need to count the total rows of [Analises_Calendario] and save it in a var and assign this value as a field in [Locais Recolha] in my field called [Analises_Recebidas].

In order to do this I have,

```
declare @analises_recebidas int;

set @analises_recebidas = (select count(*) as Total from [Analises_Calendario] as AC inner join [LocaisRecolha] as LR on AC.LidEntid=LR.LIDEntid where AC.Estado='Recebida' and (AC.Data>=(SELECT DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0))) and (AC.Data<=(SELECT DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)))) group by AC.LidEntid);

update [LocaisRecolha]
set [Analises_Recebidas]=@analises_recebidas
from [Analises_Calendario] as AC inner join [LocaisRecolha] as LR on AC.LidEntid=LR.LIDEntid
```

So I'm having the error,

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

and I don't understand because my select only return Total alias column.

Anyone can help me pls?

Comment: You have a `GROUP BY AC.LidEntid` on your select, that makes it possible to return more than 1 row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is quite inscrutable.  You are trying to assign multiple values to a single value and then trying to use the result as a scalar value in your subquery.

I think you basically want this:

```
update lr
    set Analises_Recebidas = ac.cnt
    from LocaisRecolha lr inner join
         (select LIDEntid, count(*) as cnt
          from Analises_Calendario ac
          where ac.Estado = 'Recebida' and
                ac.Data >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0)) and 
                ac.Data <= dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()) + 1, 0))
          group by LidEntid
         ) ac
         on ac.LidEntid = lr.LIDEntid;
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can try below -

```
update [LocaisRecolha]
set [Analises_Recebidas]=count(AC.LidEntid)
from [Analises_Calendario] as AC inner join [LocaisRecolha] as LR on AC.LidEntid=LR.LIDEntid
where AC.Estado='Recebida' and AC.Data>=DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0) and AC.Data<=DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0))
```